# Using <a href> to link a HTMLEntityEncoded String

Tags: html, jsp, href, xss, owasp

I have url that has been encoded by `HTMLEntityCodec` class.

Let's say the original url is https://www.example.com/aa/bb

After encoding the string becomes: https&#x3-a;&#x2f-;&#x2f-;www.example.com:4443&#x2f-;aa&#x2f-;bb

And then I tried to use the encoded url in jsp using `<a href>`,
but what I got is always https://www.example.com/aa/https:&#x2f-;&#x2f-;www.example.com:4443&#x2f-;aa&#x2f-;bb

Looks like the input is treated as a relative url and the domain is appended.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know jsp, but I guess

```
encoder.decodeForHTML(str);
```

is what you are looking for (function of HtmlEntityCodec).

Before you insert the link into the href attribute of the a-tag, you should decode the html encoded URL.

I found the function there: [Java Code Example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=winlet-master/winlet/src/main/java/com/aggrepoint/winlet/utils/EncodeUtils.java). Did this help you?